# Removing instant adhesive from skin

Tags: cleaning, home, personal-care, comfort, adhesive

Recently, I bought a powerful instant adhesive:

[image]

But after its use, I found my skin covered with a layer of adhesive liquid. I tried to remove it by rubbing my fingers on a rough surface, washing with soap and nothing seems to work. I can feel its presence on my fingers as a distinguishable layer of adhesive material. Could you please help me out with a solution to remove this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one's listed as a version of superglue, and its best not to get it on your skin! If you can't peel it off, then try nail varnish remover, but ensure the remover is acetone, there are many other versions of this product available.

http://chemistry.about.com/od/everydaychemistry/a/How-To-Remove-Super-Glue.htm

If that doesn't work, then you may need to buy a superglue remover product - Amazon sells a few, one example in the link below

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Loctite-Glue-Remover-Gel-80000655/dp/B0001P0DKG/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1450095025&sr=8-1&keywords=super+glue+remover

Comment: Pure acetone is sold as a solvent in some locations -- check where paint is sold.  It'll do a much better job removing cured cyanoacrylate than nail polish remover, and there's never a question if you got the right kind -- but read the cautions; it's very flammable, the vapor is heavier than air and can collect (causing an ignition hazard) in low spots, and the vapor is somewhat toxic.

Answer (score 0):

It is a highly adhesive product. If you have got some of it skin, there is nothing you can do. Give it a rest, and it will come off after some time.

Answer (score 0):

Pour the hot water (Not too hot) in the glue stucken area and some cold water after some time. Then Tada! You can remove them.